# Client side javascript HTML Form builder

Tags: html, forms, runtime, designer

I need a client side HTML form builder I can implement into my project to give my users to ability to add/edit form design and field properties as desired.  I am using Telerik Kendo just to provide some background and I have a basic form, however if the user needs additional fields, or even additional labels I want them to be able to edit their own forms.

I found Jot Forms and dozens more (http://www.jotform.com) but that does not work for me.  All fields are in a vertical fashion.  I need the users to be able to drop a field, move it around where ever they need.

So in the end, I need a form builder I can use in my project where users can create and use alternate forms.  They need to be able to drag, drop the form element anywhere on the page and of course edit the properties as necessary.

If there is anything out there I would really appreciate some help on this.

Answer (score 0):

I appreciate the constructive feedback. I have ventured into discovering what it would take to build one of my own.

I found most form builders already done out there that I demoed would build a beautiful form.  As long as your desired form is simple.  As I tested I found complex forms would require additional coding on the back end.  Something most users don't know how to do, and something that would be a support nightmare.

I so far have found that the JQuery UI draggable, droppable, etc. features will provide me with ample tools do build my own.  So far I have a proof of concept where I can drag items onto a workspace. The nice thing is that I can incorporate HTML code specific to my Javascript framework, Kendo.  We use it at work and it has nearly everything including drag and drop.  Just not functional in a way where I could see building a form builder.

I am learning all of this as I go, so thank you for commenting and please forgive me if I sound inexperienced.  I am, but I am not afraid and in fact love to get my hands dirty with new stuff.